# Get the values of a dynamically created textbox in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have searched a lot for this and found a bunch of things that might help, but i a, cannot implement them in my code, and b, its not exactly what i need for my code.

Essentially, i am looking to have an inventory update web form. When you get to the page, there is one drop down list, and based on which item you select (add inventory, remove inventory) different options appear on the page.

That being said, im trying to dynamically create different fields based on the autopostback dropdown list, and i have the fields appearing fine. However, i cannot get any values that i need.

For example, whenever i try to set
    theText = textBox1.Text

it comes up null.

would this be easier with java script or am i just missing something?
thanks

Comment: Could you give us a code example that you are working with right now? What does it do? What does it not do?

Answer (score 1):

Though your questions is **extremely** vague because nobody knows what your code looks like or where it is, when dealing with dynamically created controls there are two guidelines to keep in mind:

1. All controls should be created and added to the page in the `Page_Load` so that the events and properties can be set via `ViewState`.
2. When accessing properties, they need to be accessed outside of the `Page_Load` because the values would not yet be available as they have not been bound. You would need to grab these values in an event like `PreRender`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the ID of the dynamic control you can find it with Page.FindControl():
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw.aspx